# Modems unable to acquire dhcp IPs

Tags: ip, router, dhcp, isp

I work at an ISP where we use routers (7200) for dhcp.

I recently reloaded one of our dhcp routers because we had complaints from many users unable to connect and the dhcp database file it was running on seemed corrupted (size was much less than recent backups) .

After reloading with a backup file, things got better, but I find that one day later, with everything looking normal for that router - traffic, dhcp file, we still have a number of users unable to get IPs on that particular router. On moving the users to another router (VLAN - each router a separate VLAN), they are able to get IPs and browse.

Is this just a vestige of the problem day or do you know of some other specific check I can do?

I would be glad to learn from anyone's experience, I know a direct answer isn't very possible as there are so many possible variables in this case, but I'm looking for pointers, ideas that could help guide and inform me. Thank you.

Comment: Presumably you meant a CISCO 7200? if so then I'd contact them first and foremore, either they'll know about the problem and have a fix/workaround or they'll want to know about it so they can develop one.

Comment: What sort of "modems" are you referring to? What is the users' uplink type to your customer-facing routers?